# What is the difference in meaning when we use a gerund instead of a bare infinitive after the preposition "to"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Example:

"I devoted so much time to learning this skill."

And

"I devoted so much time to learn this skill."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your examples are correct, but they do indeed have different meanings.

In your first example, *to* is a preposition followed by the **object of the preposition**—the gerund *learning*:

> *I devoted so much time to **what**?*
> *I devoted so much time to **learning this skill**.*

In your second example, *to* is an infinitive marker. Combined with the base verb, it’s called an [infinitive of purpose](https://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-of-purpose). It means *in order to [verb]*:

> *I devoted so much time **why**?*
> *I devoted so much time **in order to learn this skill**.*

Answer (score 2):

“*To learning*” is correct. Devotion is always to somebody or something. The infinitive “to learn” is out of place.

Comment: This not a discussion site, and this reads like a comment. We expect citation, source etc. to support an answer.